# Google Play Services' ImageManager

Tags: android, android-volley

Wandering around the internet :) I've found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html) class at the GMS library by google.

This seems very much like Volley and the likes. And in my first look its API seems much simpler.

My question is, first of all am I getting it right or am I missing something here, and secondly does anyone here have tried using it? If so, can you compare it to Volley, Picasso etc.?

Comment: offtopic ... compare what? interface or subjective impressions of using them? or source code( :) )?

Comment: Whatever you feel like :) What most important for me is performance